# Inserting text with the Python interface

Tags: vimscript-python

I would like to insert some Python-generated text at the current cursor position in insert mode using the Vim Python interface. The closest I have so far is:

```
imap <c-x><c-r> <c-o>:python vim.current.line += "trivial example"
```

This will append "trivial example" rather than put it at the current position. How can I insert the text at the cursor instead?

Answer (score 4):

It is generally easier to use pyeval (py3eval, pyxeval) and the expression register:

```
imap <c-x><c-r> <c-r>=pyxeval('python expression')<cr>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use : py, you probably should use vim.command

```
function dosomething()
     :py import vim 
     :py vim.command("let tt ='text' ")
     return tt
endfunction
```

and call it by `<C-R>=dosomething()`

or

```
 function dosomething()
     :py import vim 
     :py vim.command("norm i"+ 'TEXT' )
endfunction
```

and call it by `<esc>:call dosomething()`